# Cognito user pool reusability

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Happy 2/22/22 2sday!

I have created a cognito user pool in which I have spent a long time configuring stuff to match my use case. The problem is that now I am creating another project that requires a user pool just like this one, and I don't want to go back and reconfigure everything. The only differences are the name of the pool, and a bit of configuration related to the federated identity providers. What is the best solution for easily recreating this user pool?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is with an Infrastructure as Code (IaC) solution. Many companies use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/intro) because it supports all the major cloud providers, so it works well in a large multi-cloud environment. If you will only ever be using AWS, you can use [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.html). If you don't mind the overhead, you also can use the AWS Amplify CLI to write the CloudFormation templates for you, which will set up a Cognito instance, and lots more besides (S3, ECS, etc).

What none of these solutions allow, though, is to take a resource which you've already configured through the AWS Console and effectively duplicate it. You *can* reference a pre-existing resource and pull info from it, like an ARN or possibly even specific attributes. But really, you should just re-implement it with IaC and then have it available for next time.

The more infrastructure you configure using code, the more reusable it is with future projects. And it helps with debugging, too, since you can then see exactly what changed when in the configuration in git. The solutions above work just fine in an account containing non-IaC-managed resources as well, so you don't have to reimplemnet everything to get started.